# Format change for Date in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a textbox and a button when pressed clones the textbox.
so first textbox is correct and displays the date:  21-03-2014

and when the other textbox of date which is cloned, displays date:03/21/2014

So in order to save into database, i wanted to have date format like 21-03-2014.

Can i have some help?

Thank you

Comment: what you tried so far ,please update your code

Comment: You will have to post your code here, how else do you expect us to help with it?

Comment: Split the date in 3 variables, year,month and day and construct the date in server side.

Comment: If you are using JQuery datepicker then there are options for format a date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code. Hope it should helpful for you. Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/Qv36W/177/)

Comment: Tried this. Still the same

Comment: @Diablo2014, Can you able to add your scripts. Better to add fiddler to find the issue. Thanks

Comment: $('input[id^=textboxDueDate]').datepicker();
        $('#buttonAddBookTrack').click(function () { var ppendedDiv = $('<div>')                .appendTo('#divOtherBooks')
                .data('divClonedTemplate', '_' + _idCount);
                    var nodeO=$('#divTemplate').children().clone()
                $(nodeO).find('input[id^=textboxDueDate]')
                 .attr('id','textboxDueDate_'+_idCount)
                 .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
                 .datepicker()
            $(nodeO).appendTo(appendedDiv)        
            _idCount++;
        });

Comment: this is the code for cloning the textboxes. Datepicker is working fine. But getting this format 03/21/2014 instead of 21-03-2014

Comment: @Diablo2014, You could add the $('input[id^=textboxDueDate]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'}); like this. I tried this method. Its working fine for me.Hope it should helpful for you. Here it the demo URL http://jsfiddle.net/Jebasuthan/f5RtT/